# How to get data From Html Attributes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Im using C#, Xaml and HTMLAgilityPack. How to i get the value of the Attributes "alt".

HTML code:

```
<img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/87168773.png" alt="Idina Menzel - Let It Go lyrics"         title="Let It Go"/>
```

How do i get "Idina Menzel - Let It Go lyrics".

C# Code:

```
var s = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Where(o => o.Attributes["alt"] != null &&  o.Attributes["alt"].Value != null);

try
{
     foreach (HtmlNode childNode in s)
     {
          pureText.Append(c + ". ");
          pureText.Append(childNode);
          pureText.Append("\n\n");
          c++;
      }
}
catch
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[@alt]` in XPath to select all `img` nodes which have `alt` attribute defined:

```
var images = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@alt]");
foreach (var img in images)
{
    // img.Attributes["alt"].Value
}
```

Concatenating all alt messages in ordered list:

```
images.Select((img,index) => new { index, alt = img.Attributes["alt"].Value })
      .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                 (sb,x) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}. {1}\n\n", x.index + 1, x.alt),
                 sb => sb.ToString());
```